# Firefox link color flickers when using transition with :hover and :visited

Tags: css, firefox

I'm testing the following code in Firefox 49.0 (under Linux Mint):

```css
a{
  font-size:50px;
  color:gray;
  font-weight:1000;
  transition:color 1s;
}
a:hover{
  color:black;
}
a:visited{
  color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<a href="">VISITED LINK</a><br>
<a href="https://google.com/randomtext">LNK NOT VISITED</a>
```

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgEmax) if you like that more. In case the code is not clear: I want the links to be constant lightgray when visited, gray when not visited, and black when hovering a not visited link. Also, I want to transition between these colors.

However, firefox seems to apply the :hover rule first to the visited links when hovered, and then the :visited rule, and also transitioning between these, thus the flickering.

I can't seem to find a workaround this.

Edit: Chrome displays it the way I want.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the `:hover` and `:visited` declarations?

Comment: @pdoherty926 Of course I have. In that case, the :hover overrides the :visited and the link diplays black on hover, without flickering (as it is supposed to, by the nature of css selector priorities).

Answer (score 2):

**I found a workaround:**
You need to add a hover state to the visited state. See code below.

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 transition: .3s color;
}

a:hover, a:visited:hover {
 color: #9097a0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Demo Link</a>
```

Comment: This is still not a complete solution, since you still can't get a transition between a :visited and a :hover state. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmoaQa (green for visibility). The color immediately switches to the default color and transitions from there to :visited:hover. But thanks, this goes half the way, much better than flickering.

Comment: Yeah thats true

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Firefox bug, the transitions are not handled correctly.

Comment: Please add the bug report number/link/identifier.

Comment: @buhtz I didn't find one yesterday. Maybe a new bug should be created or I just didn't find an existing bug (wouldn't be the first time that happens)

Comment: Than please specifiy the __status__ of a bug. This is _unreported_.

Comment: I have found it, it is reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=868975 still, I would love a workaround

Comment: It was reported in 2013 and still not fixed :/